# How to display text in Php in the same page?

Tags: php

I have a form that refer to another PHP file.

In the another PHP file I wrote:

```
echo $result;
```

And then, when the form has been submitted, that displaying the text on `$result` in a different page. How I should display it on the same page?

I want that the result will display in the index.php file.

index.php:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label for="name"></label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <label for="subject"></label>
        <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="message"></label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    <?php echo $result; ?>
</form>
```

form.php:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

        $result = "";
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        $body = "From: $email (Name: $name). \nSubject: $subject \n \nMessage:\n$message";

        if (!$_POST['name'] || !$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ||
            !$_POST['subject'] || !$_POST['message']) {
                $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invaild form. Please try again.</div>';
            }
        else {
            mail($to, $subject, $body);
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will respond you soon.</div>';
        }
        echo $result;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Make an AJAX call to that PHP file and catch the `$result`. Then append it to some element.

Comment: @JameyD I dont know Ajax...

Comment: You meant that you want to load content without reloading page?

Comment: @TRiNE Also. Listen, ill explain it better. I have a form in a file that called `index.php`. Now, I have another file called `form.php`. (I edited the question and now you can see the codes of them.) I want that the result variable will display in the page that the form is displaying. I dont want that it will transfer me to a white page with the content of $result.

Comment: I edit the question now @TRiNE

Comment: oh, simply place all the code in same file and post to itself

Comment: I thoguht about it, but there isnt another way? its looking better with two different files @TRiNE

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Comment: Removing your code affects the current answers. Please do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

How about this seperation.

**index.php**

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)){
echo "Welcome ".$_POST["name"];
}
require_once 'form.php';
?>
```

**form.php**

```
<form method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I dont understand it so much, can you use my code? ill edit the topic again, second

Comment: Again I want that the $result will be display in the index.php file, that the form will not be transfer to the form.php...

Comment: What? I dont understand what I should do. What to add the php files?

Comment: @Roy also it is better to change the topic as "how to display form and form result in same page" or something

Comment: Okay, i will. But can you explain me what to add? because I dont know what to do with the codes that you wrote above

Comment: create above two files and run index.php

Answer (score 1):

**form.php**

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label for="name"></label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
        <label for="subject"></label>
        <input class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="message"></label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once "form.php";

if(!empty($_POST)){

    $result = "";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $body = "From: $email (Name: $name). \nSubject: $subject \n \nMessage:\n$message";

    if (!$_POST['name'] || !$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ||
        !$_POST['subject'] || !$_POST['message']) {
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Invaild form. Please try again.</div>';
        }
    else {
        mail($to, $subject, $body);
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will respond you soon.</div>';
    }
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes I did it, but the problem that in "form.php" I have a various of pages that now a files -> they are sections, each section have a class, and a ID so I can identify in which section I am. the form is on "contact" section on file "form.php", so how I comes to there? because form.php is refer to the main section.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question properly. This is not a good place for discussion and this is only for asking and answering questions. Most questions, answers are general for all people which can be re-used by others. I can't make a code for you to certain scenario. I'm sorry. I think you could understand the situation. Your question may be closed after down-voting.